# PostgreSQL: how to get Day One?

Tags: postgresql-9.2, date-math

Trying to port a T-SQL CTE to PostgreSQL.  In T-SQL `cast(0 as datetime)` returns

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Is there an equivalent 'side-effect' in pg, to get Day One of the epoch?

EDIT:

```
to_timestamp(0) on my machine --returns 1969-12-31 19:00:00-05. 

select '1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamptz --returns 1970-01-01 00:00:00-05
select '1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp --returns 1/1/1970 which is the same as
select '1970-01-01 00:00:00'::date    -- returns 1/1/1970
```

I expected the cast to timestamp to return 1970-01-01 00:00:00, that is, removing the timezone but not the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by epoch you mean 1 Jan 1970 00:00 (not 1900), you can do:

```
to_timestamp(0)
```

To get the time in a particular timezone, try:

```
to_timestamp(0) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
```

or

```
to_timestamp(0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Comment: Thanks, that will do fine.

Comment: I am new to PostgreSQL, so maybe there's a setting I need to set before this will work, but when I do `to_timestamp(0)` it returns `1969-12-31 19:00:00-05`.  So it's adjusting for timezone. Is there a way to return GMT?

Comment: Thanks. That returns 1/1/1970.